# python os.listdir() for remote locations

Tags: python, remote-access

I recently noticed that

`os.listdir('http://chymera.eu/data/faceRT')`

complains about not finding my directories.

What can I do to be able to run os.listdir() on remote locations? I have checked and this is not a permissions issue, I can open the folder via my browser and my webftp client says it's 755.

Whatever I do, I would **NOT** like to have to use login information. I made a decision about sharing when I set the directory permissions. If I say r+x for everyone then I want that to mean r+x for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I solved this by using the HTMLparser to parse my web index:

```
if source == 'server':
    from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
    import urllib
    class ChrParser(HTMLParser):
        def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
            if tag =='a':
                for key, value in attrs:
                    if key == 'href' and value.endswith('.csv'):
                        pre_fileslist.append(value)
    results_dir = 'http://chymera.eu/data/faceRT'
    data_url = urllib.urlopen(results_dir).read()
    parser = ChrParser()
    pre_fileslist = []
    parser.feed(data_url) # pre_fileslist gets populated here
```

Answer (score 3):

`os.listdir` expects the argument to be a path on the filesystem.  It does not attempt to understand URLs

You can use `urllib` to request the page and parse it to find the URLs